# Python: Linear regression from Pandas df - ordinal dates conversion

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, linear-regression

First time trying to forecast using basic linear regression in Python.  Discovered I had to convert dates to ordinal dates then into a 2D numpy array.  I now want to convert the numpy array back to YYYY/MMM/DD for a useable visual plot, but am failing.  Never used numpy before, therefore x_full_month.map(dt.datetime.fromordinal) is not working, as does not seem to be valid in numpy.

```
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    model=LinearRegression()
    df['Date_Ordinal']=df['Date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
    x=df['Date_Ordinal']
    y=df['Cost']
    x_train = x.values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_train = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_pred = model.predict(x_train)
```

From the predictive model, I'm then creating a new X of ordinal dates for the full month, to get a full months response

```
    x_full_month = np.arange(737850,737880,1).reshape((-1, 1))
    y_pred_new = model.predict(x_new)
    print('predicted response:', y_pred.T, sep='\n')
```

This seems to work, however has an ordinal dated X (as expected), how would I get a nicely formatted X for plotting.  Or get this back into a Pandas array, which I'm more familiar with?  Or, am I completely going about this a roundabout way?

Edit: corrected parameter name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several hours later and I have a solution.  I'm still sure I'm going about this in-efficiently, but the steps below do work for me.

```
    # .flatten converts numpy arrays into pandas df columns
    df = pd.DataFrame(y_pred.flatten(),x_full_month.flatten())  
     
    # creates a new index (as pd.Dataframe made x_full_month the index initially)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True) 
    
    # meaningful column names
    df = df.rename(columns = {'index':'ord_date',0:'cumul_DN'}) 
    
    # Convert oridinal date to yyyy-mm-dd
    df['date']=df['ord_date'].map(dt.datetime.fromordinal)
```